# Grafana Alerting

Tags: alert, grafana, condition

Я полный новичок в работе с Grafana, есть задача создать алерт на отсутствии сессий/меток в течении 15 мин, использую Grafana v9.4.7.
Честно говоря, ума не приложу, как создать условие.